# Correct way to call a URL on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, I wrote a Java servlet to get a zip file from the server which works fine when I use a web browser to test it.

My URL looks like the following :

`https://myserver.com/Download/FileServlet?filename=users_files_3a2f51a4-9381-11e9-bc42-526af7764f64.zip&user=TAN`

This successfully downloads the files.

I'll be dynamically passing the `UUID` part of the filename (which I'll get from the database table(top most) record) and `user` variables but for the time being and testing, I've hard coded these variables.

I am wondering how should I call the above URL when a user clicks on a button. My current setup (without any URL) is as follows.

I've button in my HTML code as shown below:

`<button id="fileButton" onclick="checkFile()">Download Files</button>`

```
<script>
function checkFile(){

}

</script>
```

Is following a correct way to do it?

`<button id="fileButton" onclick="checkFile(); location.href= https://myserver.com/Download/FileServlet?filename=users_files_3a2f51a4-9381-11e9-bc42-526af7764f64.zip&user=TAN ">Download Files</button>`

So even if above approach is correct, it is very likely that the file won't be available for download as soon as user hits download button.

I might have to keep running the above URL again and again (this may not be possible in a scenario if I tie the URL with the button click), maybe using `setInterval()` method of javascript which could only be possible to do inside a function.

Comment: Why not using an **<a>** element?

Comment: You mean `<a>` instead of button?

Comment: Yes, it's what I meant.  :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call/open a URL programmatically, you can try this:

```
window.open(url,'_blank');
```

Will open a url in a new tab.

Comment: Thanks. Would I be able to make a call to the URL again an again using `setInterval()` method of Javascript? This is because I may not find what I'm looking for in my first call.

Comment: Yes. Remember, you can do the same also in vanilla js, without the need to include the entire jquery library for just some ajax calls.

Comment: I see. I am already using jQuery for other purpose so I would rather go with jQuery approach then. Thanks!

Comment: Good then. Remember to vote and accept the answer :)

Comment: I tested it and it's not sending the zip file to the browser. Maybe Ajax is not a correct way to go about it?When I put the same URL in the browser and hit enter, I can see the zip file available for download. I added `console log ("test")` inside success and it's showing in console. Not sure if I need to modify something to make it work?

Comment: Hmm. Now I understood what you want to do. You want to download a file.
Ok, I am modifying my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195314/discussion-between-tan-and-donjoe).

Answer (score -1):

adding some insights to @DonJoe 's answer
an ajax call to download location will give response headers 200 if file is ready, then facilitate download. maybe you are downloading it twice.

```
var url = 'https://myserver.com/Download/FileServlet?filename=users_files_3a2f51a4-9381-11e9-bc42-526af7764f64.zip&user=TAN'
function checkFile(){
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function (data) {
            window.open(url,'_blank');
            #or window.location.href = url

        },
        error: function () {
            setTimeout(3000, checkFile)
        }
    });
}
```

or possibly make an iframe

```
<iframe class='downloader' />

#js
var url = 'http://myserver.com/...'
checkFile = function() {
  $('.downloader').attr('src', url)
  setTimeout(3000, checkDownload)
}
var checkDownload = function() {
  if($('.downloader')[0].innerHTML.indexOf('400') > 0)
    checkFile()
}
```

this will repeatedly check the iframe content assuming a 400 response is coming when file is not ready for download.